# ASL : asl_search() can't get logs write by asl_log()

Tags: ios, macos, syslog

I want to use asl to manage logs in iOS. But I got some problem. 
In my program I use asl_log() to write logs like this:

```
asl_log(NULL, NULL, (LEVEL), "%s", [message UTF8String]);
```

And I want to read all logs use asl_search like this:

```
q = asl_new(ASL_TYPE_QUERY);
aslresponse r = asl_search(NULL, q);
```

Here is my question. I can get message that write by NSLog(), but can't get messages write by asl_log(). How can I read messages write by asl_log()? Or how to do it correctly?

Answer (score 3):

On device, I couldn't get an iOS app to read its own ASL log entries without explicitly setting `ASL_KEY_READ_UID` to "`-1`".

The behavior on the Mac (and therefore in the iOS Simulator) is different; there, by default, a process can read log entries made by other processes.

For more information, the CleanroomASL open-source project has [a summary of differences between ASL behavior on iOS devices versus the Mac](https://github.com/emaloney/CleanroomASL/#differences-between-the-device-and-simulator).

CleanroomASL provides a Swift API for reading & writing the Apple System Log.